# MySQL: No. of Connections

Tags: mysql, connections

I have a medium sized database (7 GB) with around 200 concurrent users. I am getting some database lag issues, suddenly my node-mysql client freezes during selects and inserts.

As a process of troubleshooting I checked `SHOW STATUS` on the DB. Everything seemed to be okay, but the `connections` attribute has a value of `262050`.

I want to understand if this number is okay or if the figure is exorbitant?

Comment: No, you should not be having 262050 connections to your database. Even 2620 would be too many in my view.

Comment: [Server Status Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html). *Connections - The number of connection **attempts** (successful or not) to the MySQL server.*

Comment: @Akina you should post that as an answer, and indicate not to confuse it with `threads_connected`

Answer (score 1):

[Server Status Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html)

> **Connections**
>
> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.

I.e. it is a counter which can increase only. Each attempt to connect to server, both successful and falling, increase it. Each connection, both existing and already broken, is taken into account. So this variable value can be used only for to calculate the average number of connections per some time period.

> **Threads_connected**
>
> The number of currently open connections.

It is the amount of real external connections in any state. Do not include inner server services connections (sheduler connection, for example).

> **Threads_running**
>
> The number of threads that are not sleeping.

It is the amount of real connections not in sleeping state, including inner server services connections (sheduler connection, for example).

You can see a correlation between last 2 variables while compare the output of the commands

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS 
    WHERE Variable_name IN ( /* 'Connections', */
                            'Threads_connected',
                            'Threads_running');
```

and

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

Answer (score 1):

262050 Connections per year -- Yawn.
262050 Connections per hour -- That is very high!

What is the value of `max_connections`?  `max_used_connections`?  `Threads_connected` during a spike?  Etc.

Divide by `Uptime` to get connections per second:
10th percentile:  1 connection every 2 minutes
50th percentile:  1/second
90th percentile:  25/second

Are you using InnoDB?  (MyISAM has more ways that it can apparently "freeze".)

The slowlog will help determine the villain in this drama.

See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis) for how to tackle the slowlog and the settings, including `Connections`.